# Why is this unclear when it is perfectly clear?

Tags: discussion

This question was marked unclear, but is a good, clear and concise question with great answers. Does closing a question like this a way to get it out of public view more?

[Why are academics not paid royalties on published research papers in IEEE, ACM etc.?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/109003/why-are-academics-not-paid-royalties-on-published-research-papers-in-ieee-acm-e)

Answer (score 8):

I think [Dirk's comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/109003/why-are-academics-not-paid-royalties-on-published-research-papers-in-ieee-acm-e#comment285323_109003) covers it pretty well

> I voted to close as "unclear what you are asking". The title asks why academics do [not] get get paid royalties on their papers, the body asks other questions like "shouldn't publishers not charge that much?" Or "what can be done?". This post seems to look for discussion, and not for answers.

We don't close questions to stifle particular views, but we do close questions to get them out of public view so that the OP can hopefully refine the question so that someone can provide a great answer that is useful to the OP and others.